# How to determine pivot flick is right or left?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

Which event is used to determine if the user flicked the pivot right or left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Pivot` control uses the angle reported in the `FlickEventArgs` of the `Flick` event to determine which way to navigate the items. An angle of 180 degrees means a navigation to the right, an angle of 0 degrees means a navigation to the left.

If you want to detect this in your own code you could use the `GestureService` from the [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) as described in [this article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API) or you could simply keep track of the `SelectedIndex` property on the `Pivot` control to determine which way the user flicked.

I'd be interested to know to what purpose you're going to put this knowledge :)

Comment: This has been asked before (but can't find link) they wanted to know the direction so they could animate the items in the newly visible item appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a book app, i needed to know whether to go to the next or previous page.